# How to Loop and Count Data From 2 Separate Tables in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

thank you for your help on [my previous question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyEoQ.png) about Codeigniter

**UPDATE** : Since everyone got a little confused by my question, I have edited my question.

I'm working in a banking company, and my project is creating a real-time monitoring for my company's clients transactions.

I need help in creating a HTML table that shows the total transaction of each of the Client both SUCCESS and FAILURE it. The HTML table should look like below:

[image: Example Table]

Here's my database structure (I can't change the structure, coz I don't have the root access)

***Database A*** (Contained bank name and their ID code)

*Table 1* = BankName, ATMNode, CardNode, BankGroup, CDC

***Database B*** (Contained all the transaction data like the date, the encryption and the encrypted card number)

*Table 2* = Postid, Transid, SettleID, ATMNode, Rsp_Code, CDC

Now, I have successfully looped all of the bank name in my model. All I need to do is just COUNT the SUCCESS and FAILURE row from each of the bank name and then loop the count result.

At first I created 1 function for 1 bank name, but then I got a tip from someone that's not how it works. He said that I need to create a parameter or something with the looped bank name, and then I can loop the COUNT data for each of the bank name.

So here's my model:

```
<?php class Dash_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                // Cal CI Constructor
                parent::__construct();
                // Load Database A.
                $CI = &get_instance();
                //setting the second parameter to TRUE (Boolean) the function will return the database object.
                $this->db2 = $CI->load->database('db2', TRUE);
        }

        // Get all the bank name
        public function getbanklist()
        {
            $query = $this->db2->query("SELECT BankName FROM Table1 ORDER BY BankName");
            return ($query->result());

        }

        function transapproved() // Counting Success
        {
            // Database B autoloaded in autoload.php
            $this->db->select('TransID');
            $this->db->from('Table2');
            $this->db->join('Table1', 'Table1.CDC = Table2.CDC', 'inner');
            $this->db->where('BankName', $getbanklist);
            $this->db->where('Rsp_code', '01');
            $data = $this->db->get();
            return $this->data->num_rows();

        }

        function transfailure() // Counting Failure
        {
            // Database B autoloaded in autoload.php
            $this->db->select('TransID');
            $this->db->from('Table2');
            $this->db->join('Table1', 'Table1.CDC = Table2.CDC', 'inner');
            $this->db->where('BankName', $getbanklist);
            $this->db->where('Rsp_code', '02');
            data = $this->db->get();
            return $this->data->num_rows();
        }

}

?>
```

Of course my model is not working. It didn't return anything. Even if it work, it only return one row. So I need your help guys.

And then here's my controller:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dash_control extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('dash_model');
            $this->load->library('table');
       }

    public function index()
    {
        $tmpl = array (
        'row_start'           => '<tr>',
        'row_end'             => '</tr>',
        'cell_start'          => '<td>',
        'cell_end'            => '</td>',
        );

        $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 

        $data['banknamehere'] = $this->dash_model->getbanklist();

        $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
    }


}
```

And then I passed it to my VIEW:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Bank Name</th>
<th>Trans Success</th>
<th>Trans Failure</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($banknamehere as $row)
{ ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row->banknamehere; ?></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Yes, everything didn't work. I think the key must be in the model. But I don't know how.
Thank you for your help...

Comment: What is common field in table1 and table2 ? and Why are you use table3 ?

Comment: I know it's really confusing... But the tables I've shown was just an example from my company's database... Table 1 containing the Customer's personal data, while Table 2 and 3 handles all the transaction information...

Comment: This schema is logically error. How you will point a customer from `table 2`. Ask your Company to redesign the schema or you can fix it.

Comment: okay. that is example data structure is wrong. table 1 and table 2 must have customer ID. one primary key in table 1 and foreign key in table 2. If you change this type in your table structure. then to proceed the further.

Comment: Okay, everyone seems confused, so let me redesign the structure with the real one... I'm working in a banking company, that's why I'm afraid to show the real table structure coz it's very confidential... Just give me a few minutes...

Comment: I've updated my question... Please see it... Thank you for your help guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Table structure as per the previous answer

```
Table 1 = CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerCity, CustomerCountry, CustomerGroup

Table 2 = TransactionID, CustomerCity, TransactionStatus, DateTime,CustomerId

Table 3 = TransactionID, CustomerCountry, CustomerGroup, EncryptKey,CustomerId
```

Then in your Model

the functions will be as follows

```
public function transactionsuccess()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Table1.CustomerName as Name,Count(CustomerName) as SuccessfullTransaction  FROM Table2 join Table1 ON Table1.CustomerId=Table2.CustomerId WHERE Table2.Status='Success' GROUP BY Table1.CustomerName ORDER BY Table1.CustomerName");

    return $query->result(); 
}
public function transactionfailure()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Table1.CustomerName as Name,Count(CustomerName) as FailureTransaction  FROM Table2 join Table1 ON Table1.CustomerId=Table2.CustomerId WHERE Table2.Status='Failure' GROUP BY Table1.CustomerName ORDER BY Table1.CustomerName");

    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Then in your Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $tmpl = array (
    'row_start'           => '<tr>',
    'row_end'             => '</tr>',
    'cell_start'          => '<td>',
    'cell_end'            => '</td>',
    );

    $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 


    $data['success'] = $this->dash_model->transactionsuccess();
    $data['failure'] = $this->dash_model->transactionfailure();

    $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
}
```

Then in your View file

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Customer Name</td>
  <td>Successfull Transaction</td>
  <td>Failed Transaction</td>
 </tr>
  <?php foreach (array_combine($success, $failure) as $success_row =>  $failure_row)
   { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $success_row->Name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $success_row->SuccessfullTransaction; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo failure_row->FailureTransaction; ?></td>
  </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

updated Answer:
..............................................

In Model

```
     <?php
    class Dash_model extends CI_Model 
    {
            public function __construct()
            {

                    parent::__construct();
                    $CI = &get_instance();
                    $this->db2 = $CI->load->database('db2', TRUE);
            }


            function transapproved() // Counting Success
            {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Table1.BankName as Name,Count(BankName) as   SuccessfullTransaction  FROM Table2 join Table1 ON Table1.CDC = Table2.CDC WHERE Table2.Rsp_code='01' GROUP BY Table1.BankName ORDER BY Table1.BankName");

        return $query->result(); 

            }

            function transfailure() // Counting Failure
            {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Table1.BankName as Name,Count(BankName) as FailureTransaction  FROM Table2 join Table1 ON Table1.CDC = Table2.CDC WHERE Table2.Rsp_code='02' GROUP BY Table1.BankName ORDER BY Table1.BankName");

        return $query->result(); 
            }

    }
?>
```

In Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $tmpl = array (
    'row_start'           => '<tr>',
    'row_end'             => '</tr>',
    'cell_start'          => '<td>',
    'cell_end'            => '</td>',
    );

    $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 


    $data['success'] = $this->dash_model->transapproved();
    $data['failure'] = $this->dash_model->transfailure();

    $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
}
```

In view

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Bank Name</td>
  <td>Successfull Transaction</td>
  <td>Failed Transaction</td>
 </tr>
  <?php foreach (array_combine($success, $failure) as $success_row =>  $failure_row)
   { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $success_row->Name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $success_row->SuccessfullTransaction; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $failure_row->FailureTransaction; ?></td>
  </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I've posted another answer for your updated question. Hope it works

Comment: Hi, sorry for late comment... I think this code is legit, I'm trying to use your code, let me try code it with actual query... I'll let you know soon...

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the VIEW code, here's the error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\dashboard.php on line 302
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';'

Filename: views/dashboard.php

Line Number: 302

Backtrace:

Comment: now check .. i forgot the '$' sign in front of a variable name

Answer (score 0):

In your model

```
   public function customerlist()
            {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT CustomerName,count(CustomerName) FROM Table1 ORDER BY CustomerName");

                return $query->result(); 

            }
```

count(CustomerName) wil help you to find count of names

Chnage the table structure

```
Table 1 = customer_id, CustomerName, CustomerCity, CustomerCountry, CustomerGroup

Table 2 = TransactionID, CustomerCity, TransactionStatus, DateTime,customer_id

Table 3 = TransactionID, CustomerCountry, CustomerGroup, EncryptKey,customer_id
```

Comment: yes ofcourse... if my answer is helpful for me.then please put green tick.what help you need now?